# Comparisons returning incorrect value in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have the code:

```
@echo off
set /p dec="Path? "
set patha="C:\Users\%username%\%dec%"
set /a i=2
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:import
if "%i%"=="12" goto loopend
if "!patha:~-%i%,1!"=="." set ext="!patha:~-%i%!"
set /a i=%i%+1
goto import
:loopend
echo %ext%
pause
```

It loops through the code 10 times, but when I have it echo `"!patha:~-%i%,1!"` and it echoes `"."` it doesn't set the ext variable. Am I doing comparisons wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works happily or me in W7, although

```
FOR /f %%i IN ("%patha%") DO SET ext="%%~xi"
echo %ext%
```

would seem to do the same thing.

That is, assuming you want to extract the last n characters starting "."... (that's not clear)